# Applescript & GarageSale Find & Replace on Selected Items

Tags: applescript

I found this script for search and find in GS. Its from 2008 so it was likely wirtten for the earlier version 6 as opposed to the current version 7. Its suppose to find text in the description of any current selected template and change it to whatever the user types it. It displays the search and replace boxes correctly and runs without any errors; however, no text is changed.

I have tried the publisher's forum & documentation; macscripter; and Apple's forum. I have tried modifying it multiple times however these changes produce errors that prevent it from running or it runs but does not do anything.

I am using GS 7.0.16 on OS 10.13.6.

The code appears to originate at this

https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=26963

Any idea of how to modify it?

```
set theReply1 to (display dialog "Enter text to replace" default answer "text" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue")
set origtext to text returned of theReply1

set theReply2 to (display dialog "Enter new replacement text" default answer "text" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue")
set replacetext to text returned of theReply2

to searchReplace(thisText, searchTerm, replacement)
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to searchTerm
  set thisText to thisText's text items
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replacement
  set thisText to "" & thisText
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
  return thisText
end searchReplace

tell application "GarageSale"
  repeat with aTemplate in every selected template
    set origline to get the description of aTemplate
    set the description of aTemplate to my searchReplace(origline, origtext, replacetext)
  end repeat
end tell
```

UPDATE:

I downloaded the latest beta of version 8 here:

[enter link description here](https://help.iwascoding.com/t/garagesale-8-public-beta/5643)

The above code was written for 6. The publisher apparently made a lot of changes to the scripting language from 6 to 7. The publisher includes documentation on its website for the current 7 and beta 8. These more closely match so I decided to import my data to 8 and use Applescript with that.

I modified the above code to that below by exmining some examples in the beta 8 documentation. This script will find a replace a single continous line of text. You must switch from the Preview mode to the Edit mode and copy the html you want to replace. It will not work by copying the styled text form the Preview mode.

The publisher finally added a bulk find and replace to beta 8, but its currently is having problems with finding strings with html in it.

You can use the built in search of the latest beta 8 to find "This is some text". but it will not find "This is some text"
"More text". The above script will fidn this text.

The script below also works in GS 7.0.16. Simply load into Apple's script editor and compile as an application on your desktop. Select one listing in GS or one or more folders full of listings and run the compiled script. If I am replacing a large string with another large string I find it helpful to place these into two new TextEdit documents so that I can easily copy and paste them into the two dialog boxes shown by the script.

```
set theReply1 to (display dialog "Enter text to replace" default answer "text" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue")
set origtext to (text returned of theReply1)

set theReply2 to (display dialog "Enter new replacement text" default answer "text" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue")
set replaceText to text returned of theReply2

to searchReplace(thisText, searchTerm, replacement)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to searchTerm
    set thisText to thisText's text items
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replacement
    set thisText to "" & thisText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    return thisText
end searchReplace

tell application "GarageSale"
    repeat with theListing in (get selected ebay listings)
        set origline to get the description of theListing
        set the description of theListing to my searchReplace(origline, origtext, replaceText)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Without access to the app "GarageSale" this is almost impossible to address. The search/replace code works just fine, but if GS has changed it's scripting dictionary the script could fail for that reason. Can you tell us where yo download the app, and what version of it you're using?

Comment: Not sure where it came from, but there is no `template` term in the app's scripting dictionary, so you might check the scripting dictionary of your version to see what terminology is available.  There are also AppleScript examples in the application bundle (I'm not running the app, so I don't know if these get copied to the **~/Library/Application Support/** folder).